# Upgrade ReSharper licence

Tags: licensing, resharper, upgrade

Today I have a ReSharper 5.0 license, and are looking to update it.
But my question is when I can buy the new license to be sure to upgrade to ReSharper 8.0 when it arrives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of inside knowledge from JetBrains, there's no way of knowing. The free-upgrade window (whereby anyone who buys version `n-1` just before version `n` is released gets auto-upgraded) doesn't seem to get announced before the release of version `n`.

For example, see [this blog post announcing the release of version `7.0`](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/07/resharper-70-is-released/), and note the wailing and gnashing of teeth in the comments.